# Using Keras To Predict Output Vector From Input Vector

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, vectorization, prediction

I am using Keras to work with word embeddings, trying to predict one word embedding from another. The inputs consist of a list of word embeddings, and the outputs consist of a list of word embeddings matched to the first.

While my neural model predicts consistent outcomes for individual words, these words appear to be completely unrelated and random to the input word. While this could mean there is no pattern between the input and output word embeddings, I do not really believe this is true. I think there is some issue in my code.

This is the model I have set up. input_list is a list of word embeddings generated from a pre-trained word vectorization model. output_list is the same thing. Both are formatted as numpy arrays

```
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
import keras.layers as layers
import tensorflow as tf

inputTensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(inputList)
outputTensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(outputList)
inputTensor = inputTensor[..., None]
outputTensor = outputTensor[..., None]
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(64, input_shape=(inputTensor.shape[1], inputTensor.shape[2])))
model.add(layers.Dense(64, input_shape=(inputTensor.shape[1], inputTensor.shape[2])))
model.add(layers.Dense(64, input_shape=(inputTensor.shape[1], inputTensor.shape[2])))
model.build((None, 850))
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="rmsprop", metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
```

850 is the number of dimensions per vector input
The code runs and compiles fine, and error is very low (about 0.00080161). Yet, results are random. I am not expecting perfect results, but there are 60,000 training pairs, so I'd hope for something a bit better than "Siberian husky is a type of labium"

I'm quite new to Keras, and I am assuming that something is wrong with my model. Thank you to anyone who can help!

Comment: Please read here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404075/how-should-we-handle-machine-learning-questions-asking-for-performance-improveme/